# create object from a xml stored on a server in unity

Tags: xml, unity-game-engine, unityscript

I've seen several tutorials regarding storing data from xml into unity. But I can't wrap my finger around it. I want to create a cube at runtime with information stored in a xml file on my server. The xml layout looks like following:

```
<Cubes>
    <Cube nameCube="CubeNumber1">
    <Cube colorCube="139,69,19,1">
    </Cube>
</Cubes>
```

Underneath I have a code I used so far, without the addition of calling a xml from the server (using WWW function) and linking it to this script.

```
 function Start() {
     var cube = GameObject.CreatePrimitive(PrimitiveType.Cube);
     cube.name = 'CubeNumber1';


  // color cube  
 Color colorCube = new Color(139,69,19,1);
 cube.renderer.material.color = colorCube;

 }
```

Can you guys help me with the new code (preferibly in Javascript), but also give a small explanation on how the script works (So I'll understand in future context xd ).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all you need to have a valid XML file.

**xmlcubes.txt**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<Cubes>
    <Cube nameCube="CubeNumber1" colorCube="139,69,19,1" />
    <Cube nameCube="CubeNumber2" colorCube="139,69,19,1" />
</Cubes>
```

And the javascript:

```
import System.Xml;
import System.IO;

function Start()
{
    var asset:TextAsset = Resources.Load("xmlcubes");
    if(asset != null)
    {
        var url = "http://www.yourserver.com/xmlcubes.txt";
        var www : WWW = new WWW(url);
        yield www;
        var reader:XmlTextReader = new XmlTextReader(new StringReader(www.text));
        while(reader.Read())
        {
            if(reader.Name == "Cube")
            {
                Debug.Log(reader.Name + " nameCube = " + reader.GetAttribute("nameCube"));

                var cube = GameObject.CreatePrimitive(PrimitiveType.Cube);
                cube.name = reader.GetAttribute("nameCube");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I get a semicolon issue in the part of assigning the color to the cube. But the other part works great and if I'm not mistaken I would be able to use the WWW function with files inside the Resources folder, right?

Comment: I edited the answer. You don't need to use the Resources folder if you want to read from server. You can get the data with: var www : WWW = new WWW(url);

Comment: I still get semicolon issues at the part of the colorsplit. But I don't really need that part (it was more as an example). The www function and the loading of the xml works great! only comment: because the www is in the start function you should add "yield www;" in the row below it, or else you get the message that it hasn't downloaded yet. Thank you for the great help!